# What do i do with rabbit hide

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant find any where to place it, and I can't find any way to craft it.

Is it usable, or is it designed as a souvenir / junk?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the only use for rabbit hide is to craft leather from it. Place it in a crafting grid in a 2x2 form and you will get normal leather.

This is a useful item, if you ever play on SMP that use entity clears, finding animals can be very difficult. This way you have another source for leather.

In addition to rabbit hides, rabbit will also rarely drop 'rabbits foot' which is a potion ingredient.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit_Hide

Comment: 3 sources of leather? Are you referring to villager trades?

Comment: @Ben Oh, that would be 4 then....

Comment: @Ben Once apon a time a man decided the world around him was dangerous and inhospitable. So this man, he walked 5000 blocks north from spawn, and then apon the water he came....so he made a boat, well, 3 boats because you know, lilypads. And across the ocean he went another 8000 blocks and finally, finally he saw it, the promised land. He walked on the land and looked around and everywhere there were these strange looking animals....almost cow like, but....red.

Comment: True story btw. On a server I found a massive moo shroom island/beach and made it into a base. No mobs and surrounded by 5k meters of water in every direction. Was epic. Lived on steak and mushroom soup. Had milk and leather for days.

Comment: @ydobonebi that'd make it 5 sources then

Comment: @MrLemon loot chests?

Comment: @ydobonebi Rabbits, Cows, Mooshrooms, Villagers, Horses/Donkeys (not just for glue)

Comment: @MrLemon oh duh, I actually farmed horses for leather once because I never found cows in my world. Strangest thing too. But I prefer making glue out of them ;)

Comment: With that story-like comment,do you mean that he found a Mushroom Island,isn't it? I was unlucky on my current world,though. @ydobonebi

Comment: Fishing is a source,too. @MrLemon

Comment: @MrLemon Was gonna say that but wasn't sure about it. I don't fish much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 4 rabbit hides to craft leather. This can be good if you don't have cows around.

Answer (score 2):

Because the answer to this question will likely change over time I will give you this link to keep an eye on: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit_Hide.
Also, at the time of posting this answer, you can only use it for crafting leather.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any cows around, and you want leather. What do you do?

Well the first thing people do when they can't find a cow is run around the world searching for one. And when they finally found one they don't know how to get home or where they were. Well if you're in the tutorial, you're safe because there is at least three or four cows in one of the pens.

People think rabbit hide is useless because when they try to put it on a wall or the floor it does nothing. Well, that story is about to change. If you have four rabbit hide, then you're in luck because, when you have four rabbit hide you can make leather. I'm not sure how many pieces you get but you'll get some.

Horses are also a good source of leather. And if there isn't any horses, cows, donkeys, mules, or rabbits anywhere (which isn't very common unless you're on a survival island) you're pretty much screwed.